# Sort dataframe based on column criteria

Tags: r

I need to sort the below dataframe1 based on another dataframe2 columns:

Dataframe1:

```
LC       Item     Rolledfcst
MW92    1358576     2125
RM11    1358576     3955
WK14    1358576     307 
SW92    1358576     190
MW92    1267890     200
SW92    1267890     670
RM11    1267890     890
WK14    1267890     245
```

Dataframe 2:

```
      Item   LC1    LC2     LC3
    1358576 RM11    MW92    SW92
    1358576 RM11    WK14    NA
    1267890 MW92    SW92    NA
    1267890 RM11    WK14    NA
```

Now for each Item in Dataframe1 it should sort the LC based on Dataframe2 columns in the order such that first column LC1 elements then LC2 and after that LC3.

Note: For each Item, in LC1 or LC2 or LC3 there are 2 LCs in any column then there order doesn't matter

Output Dataframe:

```
LC       Item     Rolledfcst
RM11    1358576     3955
MW92    1358576     2125
WK14    1358576     307 
SW92    1358576     190
MW92    1267890     200
RM11    1267890     890
SW92    1267890     670
WK14    1267890     245
```

Comment: Why is `RM11` present on row 1 and row 6 ?

Comment: For Item 1358576, RM11 is coming in LC1 column in dataframe2 hence it should come first in output dataframe. Similarly, for item 1267890, in dataframe2 MW92 & RM11 both are coming in LC1 column so any of them can come first. Hence, in output data frame in row5 MW92 and then in row6 RM11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `tidyverse` solution:

```
df1 <- structure(list(LC         = c("MW92", "RM11", "WK14", "SW92", "MW92", 
                                     "SW92","RM11", "WK14"), 
                      Item       = c(1358576L, 1358576L, 1358576L, 1358576L, 
                                     1267890L, 1267890L, 1267890L, 1267890L), 
                      Rolledfcst = c(2125L, 3955L, 307L, 190L, 200L, 670L, 
                                     890L, 245L)), 
                      class      = "data.frame", 
                      row.names  = c(NA, -8L))

df2 <- structure(list(Item      = c(1358576L, 1358576L, 1267890L, 1267890L), 
                      LC1       = c("RM11", "RM11", "MW92", "RM11"), 
                      LC2       = c("MW92", "WK14", "SW92", "WK14"), 
                      LC3       = c("SW92", NA, NA, NA)), 
                      class     = "data.frame",  
                      row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

First determine an order via `df2` in long format:

```
library(tidyverse)
(ord <- df2 %>%
    gather(LC, value, -Item) %>% 
    arrange(Item, LC) %>% 
    group_by(Item) %>% 
    mutate(order = as.numeric(factor(value, unique(value)))) %>% 
    filter(!is.na(order)) %>% unique())

# # A tibble: 8 x 4
# # Groups:   Item [2]
#      Item LC    value order
#     <int> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
# 1 1267890 LC1   MW92      1
# 2 1267890 LC1   RM11      2
# 3 1267890 LC2   SW92      3
# 4 1267890 LC2   WK14      4
# 5 1358576 LC1   RM11      1
# 6 1358576 LC2   MW92      2
# 7 1358576 LC2   WK14      3
# 8 1358576 LC3   SW92      4
```

Now, join `df1` and `ord` and sort to `item` and `order`:

```
left_join(df1, 
          ord %>% select(-LC), 
          by = c("Item", LC = "value")) %>% 
   arrange(desc(Item), order) %>% select(-order)

#     LC    Item Rolledfcst
# 1 RM11 1358576       3955
# 2 MW92 1358576       2125
# 3 WK14 1358576        307
# 4 SW92 1358576        190
# 5 MW92 1267890        200
# 6 RM11 1267890        890
# 7 SW92 1267890        670
# 8 WK14 1267890        245
```

---

As per the comments here a pure base `R` solution:

```
## transform data to long format
ord <- reshape(df2, varying=names(df2)[-1], direction = "long", v.names = "LC")
## sort according to item and time
ord <- ord[order(-ord$Item, ord$time), ]
## remove NAs
ord <- ord[!is.na(ord$LC),]
## remove duplicates
ord <- ord[!duplicated(ord[, c(1, 3)]), ]
## add the order
split(ord$id, ord$Item) <- lapply(split(ord$id, ord$Item), seq_along)
## merge the data
df.res <- merge(df1, ord[, -2], by = c("Item", "LC"))
## sort according to order
df.res[order(-df.res$Item, df.res$id), -4]
#      Item   LC Rolledfcst
# 6 1358576 RM11       3955
# 5 1358576 MW92       2125
# 8 1358576 WK14        307
# 7 1358576 SW92        190
# 1 1267890 MW92        200
# 2 1267890 RM11        890
# 3 1267890 SW92        670
# 4 1267890 WK14        245
```

Comment: Can we use something else instead  of groupby here?

Comment: What is the issue with `group_by`?

Comment: In R studio groupby is working perfectly fine but I am running it on my company tool R server where groupby is not supported

Comment: Are you saying that `dplyr` is not installed on your company's pc?

Comment: It is installed but with this version: dplyr /usr/local/lib/R/site-library 0.5.0

Comment: Can you suggest me some other solution instead of groupby here?

Comment: Getting this error: Error in -df.res$Item: invalid argument to unary operator

Comment: I guess your `Item` is a factor or a character. Just remove the `-` in this case and you will sort increasingly instead of decreasingly.

Comment: Base R code is working perfectly. There is a slight modification if that can be handled. In DF2, in LC1 column we have RM11 & MW92 and MW92 is present in LC2 column so RM11 should come first and then MW92 because MW92 is also present in LC2. Similarly in LC2 column SW92 is present and it is also present in LC3 so it should come at last in sorting order because it is present in LC3 also.

Comment: Can this be handled if something is coming in 2 columns like LC2 & LC3 column then it should come according to the sorting criteria of LC3 position

Answer (score 2):

A base R approach using `split` and `mapply`. We convert `Item` to `factor` based on it's occurrence in `df1` then `split` row numbers of `df1` based on `Item` column and `match` those `LC` values with unlisted values of `df2` to get original row numbers in sorted manner to subset.

```
df1$Item <- factor(df1$Item, levels = unique(df1$Item))
df2$Item <- factor(df2$Item, levels = unique(df1$Item))

df1[c(mapply(function(x, y) y[match(df1$LC[y], unique(unlist(x)))], 
           split(df2[-1], df2$Item), split(seq_along(df1$LC), df1$Item))), ]


#    LC    Item Rolledfcst
#2 RM11 1358576       3955
#1 MW92 1358576       2125
#3 WK14 1358576        307
#4 SW92 1358576        190
#5 MW92 1267890        200
#7 RM11 1267890        890
#6 SW92 1267890        670
#8 WK14 1267890        245
```

Comment: Not working as expected, giving below error:
In split.default(x = seq_len(nrow(x)), f = f, drop = drop, ...) :
  data length is not a multiple of split variable

In Dataframe1 I have 3more columns, does it make any difference??

Comment: @AnshulS No it should not make any difference. Do you have any `NA` values in `df1$Item` ? The error is form this line `split(seq_along(df1$LC), df1$Item)` it seems.

Comment: Yes, I have some values where NA is present. How to tackle that?

Comment: Select only rows in `df1` where there are no `NA`'s `df3 <- df1[!is.na(df1$Item), ]` and then use `df3` in the code instead of `df1`.

Comment: I removed the NAs still getting this error:
In split.default(x = seq_len(nrow(x)), f = f, drop = drop, ...) :
  data length is not a multiple of split variable

Answer (score 1):

Read in Data:

```r
df1 <- read.table(text = 'LC       Item     Rolledfcst
MW92    1358576     2125
RM11    1358576     3955
WK14    1358576     307 
SW92    1358576     190
MW92    1267890     200
SW92    1267890     670
RM11    1267890     890
WK14    1267890     245', header = T)


df2 <- read.table(text = ' Item   LC1    LC2     LC3
    1358576 RM11    MW92    SW92
    1358576 RM11    WK14    NA
    1267890 MW92    SW92    NA
    1267890 RM11    WK14    NA', header = T)
```

Gather LC columns into single column and create an ID column containing the sort order

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df2 %>%
  gather(LC, value,2:4) %>%
  mutate(sort_id = paste0(Item,value))

#     Item  LC value     sort_id
#1  1358576 LC1  RM11 1358576RM11
#2  1358576 LC1  RM11 1358576RM11
#3  1267890 LC1  MW92 1267890MW92
#4  1267890 LC1  RM11 1267890RM11
#5  1358576 LC2  MW92 1358576MW92
#6  1358576 LC2  WK14 1358576WK14
#7  1267890 LC2  SW92 1267890SW92
#8  1267890 LC2  WK14 1267890WK14
#9  1358576 LC3  SW92 1358576SW92
#10 1358576 LC3  <NA>   1358576NA
#11 1267890 LC3  <NA>   1267890NA
#12 1267890 LC3  <NA>   1267890NA
```

Create a sort_id column in the same way for `df1` and apply the factor levels from `df2`. The factor levels will govern the sort order when using `arrange`.

```
df1 %>%
  mutate(sort_id = factor(paste0(Item,LC), levels = unique(df2$sort_id)),
         Item = factor(Item, levels = unique(df2$Item))) %>%
  group_by(Item) %>%
  arrange(sort_id, .by_group = T) %>%
  select(-sort_id)

#LC    Item    Rolledfcst
#  <fct> <fct>        <int>
#1 RM11  1358576       3955
#2 MW92  1358576       2125
#3 WK14  1358576        307
#4 SW92  1358576        190
#5 MW92  1267890        200
#6 RM11  1267890        890
#7 SW92  1267890        670
#8 WK14  1267890        245
```

Comment: Instead of groupby can we use something else?

Comment: Also, when I am trying to use df1 again ahead for some computations it is giving me below error:
Error in FUN(left, right) : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: It may be due to the grouping. If you want to use df1 for further calculations try `%>% ungroup` before proceeding